# Alexander goes cafeteria

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In Alexander's program there are $50$ girls and $50$ boys. They use a cafeteria of 25 4-tables, enough to cover the peak hour.

Alexander would like to talk with girls rather than boys during the pause; so, he assumes on average a table will have $2$ girls and $2$ boys.

After taking his seat at a table, he discovers the cruel reality : on average there are only $1.5$ girls at his table and $2.5$ boys.

Why the girls are avoiding Alexander ? Why they are choosing other tables ?

Comment: How can you have the average of *his* table?  There is only one table that is his so if it has 2 girls the average of his table is 2 girls, if it has one girl the average is one girl, and so on.  How can the average be $1.5$.

Comment: Anyway, there are only three seats free at his table.  So the expect value after several times will have half of them will be occupied with girls half with boys.  Or $1.5$.

Comment: Yes, meanwhile he looks at other tables and see an average of 2 girls/table.

Comment: The other tables have 4 seats available.  His table only has 3.  If there were a table that seated 10 there'd be 5 girls.  Would it be reasonable for him to be upset that his table with 3 seats has few girls than a table with 10 seats?  We should he expect his table with only 3 free seats to have the same number of girls as a table with 4 free seats.

Comment: His table has $1.5$ boys that are not him and $1.5$ girls that are not him.  50-50.  The other tables  have $2$ boys that are not him and $2$ girls that are not him.  50-50.  If Alexander wants to increase the average numbers of boys at his table he should kill himself and visit as a ghost.  Then the person sitting in his seat will have a 50% chance (more or less) of being a girl.

Comment: [Alexander's had a busy hour](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816201/alexander-takes-the-train), nbegginer. Maybe give him/it a rest, and view and learn from the answers you've received before making Alexander do more.

Comment: given the skew answer below, it seams that what ever distribution is given and Alexander steps in somehow, the "ghosts" estimations fall :)

Comment: Anonymus, I really appreciate your involvement but I had enough answer. Statistics is the science of “them” -well said. The statistician should be a "ghost". The book authors never reserve a flight seat, never complete a multiple choice test and they never buy defective radio components .  The authors never get involved!   Let it go :)  such things are not in the culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic question in probability theory. The fact that Alexander, who is a boy, certainly sits at his own table skewes the distribution -- for example, he will never see $4$ girls at his table.

The easiest way to think about it is that there are really $3$ places left after Alexander sits, for $50$ girls and $49$ (N.B. *not $50$*) boys. On average, a little over half of these seats ($3\times 50/99 \approx 1.515$) will be taken by girls, and a little less than half $(3 \times 49/99 \approx 1.485)$ will be taken by boys *other than Alexander*. So, Alexander is indeed *slightly* unlucky: he should see about $1.515$ girls and $2.485$ boys (including himself) at his table, but maybe he just did not get enough samples!

Answer (score 5):

This question is very confusingly worded, and I don't entirely agree with its premise. But I believe the point is: Alexander is a boy, so any table he sits at will have one of the following distributions (representing by 'B' a boy and by 'G' a girl): **B**BBB, **B**BBG, **B**BGG, or **B**GGG (I've **bolded** Alexander in each case). This means the average number of boys is $\frac{4+3+2+1}{4} = 2.5$, and the average number of girls is $\frac{0+1+2+3}{4} = 1.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander should consider that he's a boy himself, and that the expected value of a random variable (following a binomial distribution in this case) is a linear function. He should also consider working out and exercising proper hygiene.